# JavaScript- Changing input label color?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change the color of my input label through JavaScript. I'm doing the same with list items and selecting the input. They both work fine. However, it won't change the color of the label when I have it written the same way. Is my code incorrect? or is there another way to complete this task in a similar fashion?

My code:

```
    //Highlights current page from submenu- This works
    link = document.getElementById("<?php echo "$link";?>");  
    link.style.background = "#CCCCCC";
    link.style.color = "#3385D6";
    link.style.fontWeight = "bold";     
    link.style.border = "1px solid";
    link.style.borderColor = "#BBBBBB";

    //Highlights current submenu tab
    subbtn = document.getElementById("<?php echo "$subTab";?>");
    subbtn.checked= true;   
    //Doesn't work
    subbtn.style.background = "#CCCCCC";
    subbtn.style.color = "#3385D6";
    subbtn.style.fontWeight = "bold";
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="reveal-email">
<li><label for="reveal-email" >Tab that i want to change</label></li>
```

Comment: What does `<?php echo "$subTab";?>` output?

Comment: Now that you've posted your HTML, the issue is indeed what I mention in my answer, if `subbtn` is the radio button element.

Comment: Note: Your HTML as posted is invalid: `input` and `li` cannot be siblings. `li` elements are only allowed as direct children of `ul` and `ol` elements (well, ignoring `template`); `input` elements are not allowed to be direct children of `ul` or `ol` elements. It doesn't change the answer, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I put it as a li to line it correctly within a list, because I have links going across that div container and when its not a li its slightly below the others. I'm not sure how to fix that just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your using a `checked` property on it, I'm going to guess that `subbtn` is an `input type="checkbox"` or `input type="radio"`. So you're not setting the color and background of the *label* at all, that's a separate element.

<s>If your HTML has the `input` *inside* the `label` (as is frequently the case), then:</s>

```
var parentStyle = subbtn.parentNode.style;
parentStyle.background = "#CCCCCC";
parentStyle.color = "#3385D6";
parentStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
```

**Live Example**:

```js
var subbtn = document.getElementById("subbtn");
var parentStyle = subbtn.parentNode.style;
parentStyle.background = "#CCCCCC";
parentStyle.color = "#3385D6";
parentStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="subbtn"> This is the label
</label>
```

*(The HTML you added indicates that you're using `for` instead, so see below.)*

If your HTML has them separated and linked by the `for` attribute on the `label` matching the `id` of the checkbox, then the first line changes somewhat:

```
var parentStyle = document.querySelector('label[for="' + subbtn.id + '"]').style;
```

**Live Example**:

```js
var subbtn = document.getElementById("subbtn");
var parentStyle = document.querySelector('label[for="' + subbtn.id + '"]').style;
parentStyle.background = "#CCCCCC";
parentStyle.color = "#3385D6";
parentStyle.fontWeight = "bold";
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="subbtn">
<label for="subbtn">This is the label</label>
```

If you're not linking them in either way, you should, so that clicking the label will toggle the checkbox.

Comment: I don't know javascript, this is my first attempt at using it. So I apologize, but where would I put the colors, ect.. in for the second one. It'd be just like the first, correct? also I put my html in the question to make it easier hopefully to understand.

Comment: @user5166162: Yes, just like the first example. As I said, "...the **first line** changes somewhat..." (you can also look at the working snippet to see things in context).